# Parse Subdomain on localhost

Tags: c#, debugging, asp.net-mvc-3, subdomain

**The Setup**

I am building an app using ASP.NET MVC3, the application makes use of sub domains, i added the following in my hosts file : `127.0.0.1       students.localhost`.

This all seems fine, when i debug, the browser opens up `localhost:{PORT}`, i can browse the site, i can also open up: `students.localhost:{PORT}`, and the site works perfectly.

*In case you were wondering, i made use of: [Maarten Balliauw's](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/05/20/ASPNET-MVC-Domain-Routing.aspx) code to achieve the routing requirements in MVC and subdomains*

**The Problem**

I need to somehow find out what subdomain the user is accessing the site from. If i debug, my and go to my subdomain:`http://students.localhost:{PORT}` Request.Url is : `http://localhost:{PORT}`, for some reason the deubugger (or ASP.NET Development Server) is not picking up `students`.

Please do not go into the TLD descussion trying to explain what a subdomain really is, all i need is the first string after `http://`. in local and production this WILL be my subdomain.

Thanx in advance

---

**UPDATED:**
I managed to get the desired result by making use of:`Request.Headers["host"]`, it would be interesting to find out why Request.Url does not contain the `students` substring.

Comment: Hey Dusty, when I inspect Request.Url.Host locally I get the "students" substring. I haven't done anything special to make this happen so I'm not certain why Request.Url is empty for you. I'll keep poking around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way to do this is to put a fully qualified domain name in hosts.  If the production site is subdomain.domain.com, I like to use subdomain.domain.local and just map this to 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

```
new System.Uri(Request.RawUrl).Host
```

I think this will be the real hostname.

Comment: Request.RawUrl = `/`, i am unable to find aything in the request that resembles `students`